# Adobe edge - get scroll position value

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, parallax, adobe-edge

I'm trying to code something in Adobe edge.

Currently I can get the mouse position and control the timeline with the x value.

```
mousemove:
this.onMove(posX, posY);

compositionready:
this.onMove=function(posX, posY){
timelinecontrol = Number(posX)*80;
console.log(timelinecontrol);
sym.stop(timelinecontrol);
}
```

How can I get the scroll distance from the top of the page and use it instead of posX?

Comment: Thanks for editing all of my personal comments out. I'm not a robot, you don't have to make me talk like one.

What i said was - 

I cant for the life of me work out how to get the scroll distance from the top of the page and use it instead of posX. Out of my depth now....

THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.onMove(e.pageX, e.pageY);

// insert code to be run when the composition is fully loaded here
this.onMove=function(posX, posY) {
    timelinecontrol = Number(posX)*2;
    console.log(timelinecontrol);
    sym.stop(timelinecontrol);


    sym.$("lblX").html("X:"+posX);
    sym.$("lblY").html("Y:"+posY);

}
```